# Python selecting a value in a combo box and HTTP POST

Tags: asp.net, python, http, web-scraping

In Python, I'm trying to read the values on http://utahcritseries.com/RawResults.aspx.  How can I read years other than the default of 2002?

So far, using mechanize, I've been able to reference the SELECT and list all of its available options/values but am unsure how to change its value and resubmit the form.

I'm sure this is a common issue and is frequently asked, but I'm not sure what I should even be searching for.

Comment: It seems to be some kind of ASP.NET scaffolding-type thing, since the code looks very computer-generated. Perhaps a bit of rewording could help, something like "Getting data from AJAX ASP.NET application"..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So how about this:

```
from mechanize import Browser
year="2005"

br=Browser()
br.open("http://utahcritseries.com/RawResults.aspx")
br.select_form(name="aspnetForm")
control=br.form.find_control("ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSeries")
control.set_value_by_label((year,))
response2=br.submit()

print response2.read()
```

Answer (score 0):

With problems relating to AJAX-loading of pages, use [Firebug!](http://getfirebug.com/)

Install and open Firebug (it's a Firefox plugin), go to the Net page, and make sure "All" is selected. Open the URL and change the select box, and see what is sent to the server, and what is received.

It seems the catchily-named field `ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSeries` is what is responsible.. Does the following work..?

```
import urllib

postdata = {'ctl00$ContentPlaceHolder1$ddlSeries': 9}

src = urllib.urlopen(
    "http://utahcritseries.com/RawResults.aspx",
    data = urllib.urlencode(postdata)
).read()

print src
```

Comment: No, that doesn't work-when I print src, I still see values from 2002.  I tried something similar(albeit MANY more lines ;) - I'm just a rookie )